# Orbeon 4 tab loading issue

Tags: tabs, orbeon, page-refresh

We migrated my Orbeon to Version 4.2 and had this problem that we previously did not had before when using the old version. After login using an username, the tabs did not shown in the page, it only show after refreshed the page. We did not had this problem using orbeon 3.9 and older version of orbeon. We unable to find the source of this problem and the solutions for it, suspect it might cause by the sessions. Please help with this problem.

Thanks

basically we use web-inf/web.xml to control who can access the url, code as below :

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>UIS Protected Resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/uis-welcome/login/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>registered</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/uis-authentication/login</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/uis-authentication/login-error</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>registered</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

and we filter user access at config/theme.xsl file, code as follow :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:f="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/formatting"
    xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:version="java:org.orbeon.oxf.common.Version">

    <xsl:import href="theme-plain.xsl"/>

    <!-- This contains some useful request information -->
    <xsl:variable name="request" select="doc('input:request')" as="document-node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="session" select="doc('input:session')" as="document-node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="current-user-role" select="$session/users/user/user_role" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="current-user-agent" select="$request/*/headers/header[name='user-agent']/value" as="xs:string"/>

    <!-- List of applications -->
    <xsl:variable name="applications-welcome" select="doc('/ubd_gen_next_degrees-apps-list-welcome.xml')" as="document-node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="applications-student" select="doc('/ubd_gen_next_degrees-apps-list-student.xml')" as="document-node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="applications-admission-staff" select="doc('/ubd_gen_next_degrees-apps-list-admission-staff.xml')" as="document-node()"/>

    <!-- Current application id -->
    <xsl:variable name="current-application-id" select="tokenize(doc('input:request')/*/request-path, '/')[4]" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="current-category-id" select="tokenize(doc('input:request')/*/request-path, '/')[3]" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="current-section-id" select="tokenize(doc('input:request')/*/request-path, '/')[2]" as="xs:string"/>

    <!-- Try to obtain a meaningful title for the example -->
    <xsl:variable name="title" select="if (/xh:html/xh:head/xh:title != '')
                                       then /xh:html/xh:head/xh:title
                                       else if (/xh:html/xh:body/xh:h1)
                                            then (/xh:html/xh:body/xh:h1)[1]
                                            else '[Untitled]'" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:template match="xh:head">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xh:link rel="stylesheet" href="/fr/style/bootstrap_all/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
            <xh:link rel="stylesheet" href="/fr/style/form-runner-bootstrap-override.css" type="text/css"/>
            <xh:link rel="stylesheet" href="/config/theme-staff/examples.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
            <xh:link rel="stylesheet" href="/fr/style/menu_style.css" type="text/css" />
            <xh:link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ops/images/orbeon-icon-16.ico"/>
            <xh:link rel="icon" href="/ops/images/orbeon-icon-16.png" type="image/png"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xh:body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @class"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="class" select="string-join(('orbeon', @class), ' ')"/>
            <xh:div class="container">
                <xh:div align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="string($request/*/remote-user)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(string($request/*/remote-user)) = 0">
                     | <xh:a href="/uis-welcome/login/"><b>Login</b></xh:a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                     | <xh:a href="/uis-authentication/logout?global=true"><b>Logout</b></xh:a>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </xh:div>

                <xh:ul id="nav">

                    <xsl:for-each select="$applications-welcome/*/section">

                        <xsl:variable name="main-selected" as="xs:boolean" select="@sid = $current-section-id"/>

                        <xh:li class="{if ($main-selected) then 'current' else ''}">
                            <xh:a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a>
                            <xh:ul>
                                <xsl:for-each select="./category">
                                    <xh:li>
                                        <xh:a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a>
                                        <xh:ul>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="./application">
                                                <xh:li><xh:a href="/{@sid}/{@id}/"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a></xh:li>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xh:ul>
                                    </xh:li>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xh:ul>                            
                        </xh:li>

                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <xsl:for-each select="$session/users/user">

                        <xsl:if test="matches(.,'student')">

                            <xsl:for-each select="$applications-student/*/section">

                                <xsl:variable name="main-selected" as="xs:boolean" select="@sid = $current-section-id"/>

                                <xh:li class="{if ($main-selected) then 'current' else ''}">
                                    <xh:a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a>
                                    <xh:ul>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="./category">
                                            <xh:li>
                                                <xh:a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a>
                                                <xh:ul>
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="./application">
                                                        <xh:li><xh:a href="/{@sid}/{@id}/"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a></xh:li>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </xh:ul>
                                            </xh:li>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xh:ul>                            
                                </xh:li>

                            </xsl:for-each>

                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="matches(.,'admission-staff')">

                            <xsl:for-each select="$applications-admission-staff/*/section">

                                <xsl:variable name="main-selected" as="xs:boolean" select="@sid = $current-section-id"/>

                                <xh:li class="{if ($main-selected) then 'current' else ''}">
                                    <xh:a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a>
                                    <xh:ul>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="./category">
                                            <xh:li>
                                                <xh:a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a>
                                                <xh:ul>
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="./application">
                                                        <xh:li><xh:a href="/{@sid}/{@id}/"><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></xh:a></xh:li>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </xh:ul>
                                            </xh:li>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xh:ul>                            
                                </xh:li>

                            </xsl:for-each>

                        </xsl:if>

                    </xsl:for-each>                     

                </xh:ul>

                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xh:div>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

when we tried to debug from the epilogue-servlet.xpl:
    <p:processor name="oxf:scope-generator">
        <p:input name="config">
            <config>
                <key>requserdata</key>
                <scope>session</scope>
                <session-scope>application</session-scope>
            </config>
        </p:input>
        <p:output name="data" debug="true" id="session"/>
    </p:processor>
```

the output data will only have data, AFTER refresh the page.

Here is the epilogue-servlet.xpl

```
<p:config xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
          xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
          xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
          xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

    <!-- The document produced by the page view with XForms processing performed -->
    <p:param type="input" name="xformed-data"/>
    <!-- The raw document produced by the page view -->
    <!--    <p:param type="input" name="data"/>-->
    <!-- The XML submission if any -->
    <p:param type="input" name="instance"/>

    <p:processor name="oxf:scope-generator">
        <p:input name="config">
            <config>
                <key>requserdata</key>
                <scope>session</scope>
                <session-scope>application</session-scope>
            </config>
        </p:input>
        <p:output name="data" id="session"/>
    </p:processor>

    <!-- Get request information -->
    <p:processor name="oxf:request">
        <p:input name="config">
            <config>
                <include>/request/container-type</include>
                <include>/request/request-path</include>
                <include>/request/headers/header[name = 'user-agent']</include>
                <include>/request/headers/header[name = 'accept']</include>
                <!-- Return all parameters so they are made available to the theme -->
                <include>/request/parameters/parameter</include>
                <include>/request/remote-user</include>

            </config>
        </p:input>
        <p:output name="data" id="request"/>
    </p:processor>

    <!-- The container is a servlet -->
    <p:choose href="#xformed-data">
        <!-- XHTML detection. Apply the theme, rewrite URLs, and serialize to HTML or XHTML. -->
        <p:when test="/xh:html">

            <!-- Pick theme -->
            <p:choose href="#request">
                <p:when test="/request/parameters/parameter[name = 'orbeon-theme']/value = 'plain'">
                    <!-- Plain theme -->
                    <p:processor name="oxf:identity">
                        <p:input name="data">
                            <config>oxf:/config/theme-plain.xsl</config>
                        </p:input>
                        <p:output name="data" id="theme-config"/>
                    </p:processor>
                </p:when>
                <!-- Get regular, embeddable or renderer theme -->
                <p:otherwise>
                    <p:processor name="oxf:identity">
                        <p:input name="data"
                                 href="aggregate('config', #request#xpointer(for $app in tokenize(/request/request-path, '/')[2] return
                                            for $is-embeddable in
                                                p:property('oxf.epilogue.embeddable')
                                                    or /request/parameters/parameter[name = ('orbeon-embeddable', 'orbeon-portlet')]/value = 'true' return
                                            for $is-renderer in
                                                p:get-request-attribute('oxf.xforms.renderer.deployment', 'text/plain') = ('separate', 'integrated') return
                                            for $app-style in concat('oxf:/apps/', $app, if ($is-embeddable) then '/theme-embeddable.xsl' else '/theme.xsl') return
                                            if (not($is-renderer) and doc-available($app-style))
                                                then $app-style
                                                else if ($is-embeddable) then p:property('oxf.epilogue.theme.embeddable')
                                                     else if ($is-renderer) then p:property('oxf.epilogue.theme.renderer')
                                                     else p:property('oxf.epilogue.theme')))"/>
                        <p:output name="data" id="theme-config"/>
                    </p:processor>
                </p:otherwise>
            </p:choose>

            <!-- Apply theme if needed -->
            <p:choose href="#request"><!-- dummy test input -->
                <p:when test="not(p:property('oxf.epilogue.use-theme') = false())">
                    <!-- Theme -->
                    <p:processor name="oxf:url-generator">
                        <p:input name="config" href="#theme-config"/>
                        <p:output name="data" id="theme"/>
                    </p:processor>
                    <p:processor name="oxf:unsafe-xslt">
                        <p:input name="data" href="#xformed-data"/>
                        <p:input name="instance" href="#instance"/>
                        <p:input name="request" href="#request"/>
                        <p:input name="session" href="#session"/>
                        <p:input name="config" href="#theme"/>
                        <p:output name="data" id="themed-data"/>
                    </p:processor>
                </p:when>
                <p:otherwise>
                    <!-- No theme -->
                    <p:processor name="oxf:identity">
                        <p:input name="data" href="#xformed-data"/>
                        <p:output name="data" id="themed-data"/>
                    </p:processor>
                </p:otherwise>
            </p:choose>

            <!-- Perform URL rewriting if needed -->
            <p:choose href="#request">
                <p:when test="not(starts-with(/request/request-path, '/xforms-renderer') and not(p:property('oxf.epilogue.renderer-rewrite')))">
                    <!-- Rewriting -->
                    <p:processor name="oxf:xhtml-rewrite">
                        <p:input name="data" href="#themed-data"/>
                        <p:output name="data" id="rewritten-data"/>
                    </p:processor>
                </p:when>
                <p:otherwise>
                    <!-- No rewriting -->
                    <p:processor name="oxf:identity">
                        <p:input name="data" href="#themed-data"/>
                        <p:output name="data" id="rewritten-data"/>
                    </p:processor>
                </p:otherwise>
            </p:choose>

            <!-- Choose between XHTML output and HTML output -->
            <p:choose href="#request">
                <p:when test="p:property('oxf.epilogue.output-xhtml')">
                    <!-- Produce XHTML output -->
                    <p:choose href="#request">
                        <p:when test="contains(/request/headers/header[name = 'accept'], 'application/xhtml+xml')">
                            <p:processor name="oxf:plain-xhtml-converter">
                                <p:input name="data" href="#rewritten-data"/>
                                <p:output name="data" id="xhtml-data"/>
                            </p:processor>
                            <p:processor name="oxf:xml-converter">
                                <p:input name="config">
                                    <config>
                                        <method>xhtml</method>
                                        <omit-xml-declaration>true</omit-xml-declaration>
                                        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                                        <content-type>application/xhtml+xml</content-type>
                                        <indent>true</indent>
                                        <indent-amount>0</indent-amount>
                                    </config>
                                </p:input>
                                <p:input name="data" href="#xhtml-data"/>
                                <p:output name="data" id="converted"/>
                            </p:processor>
                        </p:when>
                        <p:otherwise>
                            <p:processor name="oxf:plain-html-converter">
                                <p:input name="data" href="#rewritten-data"/>
                                <p:output name="data" id="xhtml-data"/>
                            </p:processor>
                            <p:processor name="oxf:html-converter">
                                <p:input name="config">
                                    <config>
                                        <version>5.0</version>
                                        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                                        <indent>true</indent>
                                        <indent-amount>0</indent-amount>
                                    </config>
                                </p:input>
                                <p:input name="data" href="#xhtml-data"/>
                                <p:output name="data" id="converted"/>
                            </p:processor>
                        </p:otherwise>
                    </p:choose>
                </p:when>
                <p:otherwise>
                    <!-- Produce HTML output -->

                    <!-- For embeddable, don't put a doctype declaration -->
                    <p:choose href="#request">
                        <p:when test="(p:property('oxf.epilogue.embeddable')
                             or (/request/parameters/parameter[name = ('orbeon-embeddable', 'orbeon-portlet')]/value = 'true'))">
                            <p:processor name="oxf:identity">
                                <p:input name="data">
                                    <config>
                                        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                                        <indent>true</indent>
                                        <indent-amount>0</indent-amount>
                                    </config>
                                </p:input>
                                <p:output name="data" id="html-converter-config"/>
                            </p:processor>
                        </p:when>
                        <p:otherwise>
                            <p:processor name="oxf:identity">
                                <p:input name="data">
                                    <config>
                                        <version>5.0</version>
                                        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                                        <indent>true</indent>
                                        <indent-amount>0</indent-amount>
                                    </config>
                                </p:input>
                                <p:output name="data" id="html-converter-config"/>
                            </p:processor>
                        </p:otherwise>
                    </p:choose>

                    <p:processor name="oxf:plain-html-converter">
                        <p:input name="data" href="#rewritten-data"/>
                        <p:output name="data" id="xhtml-data"/>
                    </p:processor>

                    <!-- Convert to HTML, choosing between embeddable and plain -->
                    <p:processor name="oxf:html-converter">
                        <p:input name="config" href="#html-converter-config"/>
                        <p:input name="data" href="#xhtml-data"/>
                        <p:output name="data" id="converted"/>
                    </p:processor>

                </p:otherwise>
            </p:choose>

            <!-- Serialize to HTTP -->
            <p:processor name="oxf:http-serializer">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <!-- NOTE: converters specify content-type -->
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#converted"/>
            </p:processor>
        </p:when>
        <!-- Plain HTML detection. No theme is applied, but URLs are rewritten. -->
        <p:when test="/html">
            <!-- Rewrite all URLs in HTML documents -->
            <p:processor name="oxf:html-rewrite" >
                <p:input name="data" href="#xformed-data" />
                <p:output name="data" id="rewritten-data" />
            </p:processor>
            <!-- Output regular HTML doctype -->
            <p:processor name="oxf:html-converter">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <version>5.0</version>
                        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                        <indent>true</indent>
                        <indent-amount>0</indent-amount>
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#rewritten-data"/>
                <p:output name="data" id="converted"/>
            </p:processor>
            <p:processor name="oxf:http-serializer">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <!-- NOTE: HTML converter specifies text/html content-type -->
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#converted"/>
            </p:processor>
        </p:when>
        <!-- XSL-FO detection. Use the XSL-FO serializer -->
        <p:when test="p:property('oxf.epilogue.process-xslfo') and /fo:root">
            <p:processor name="oxf:xslfo-converter">
                <p:input name="config"><config/></p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#xformed-data"/>
                <p:output name="data" id="converted"/>
            </p:processor>
            <p:processor name="oxf:http-serializer">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <header>
                            <name>Content-Disposition</name>
                            <value>attachment; filename=document.pdf</value>
                        </header>
                        <!-- NOTE: XSL-FO converter specifies application/pdf content-type -->
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#converted"/>
            </p:processor>
        </p:when>
        <!-- SVG detection -->
        <p:when test="p:property('oxf.epilogue.process-svg') and /svg:svg">
            <p:processor name="oxf:svg-converter">
                <p:input name="config"><config/></p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#xformed-data"/>
                <p:output name="data" id="converted"/>
            </p:processor>
            <p:processor name="oxf:http-serializer">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        NOTE: SVG converter specifies content-type, usually image/png
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#converted"/>
            </p:processor>
        </p:when>
        <!-- Atom detection -->
        <p:when test="/atom:feed">
            <p:processor name="oxf:xml-converter">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                        <content-type>application/atom+xml</content-type>
                        <indent>false</indent>
                        <indent-amount>0</indent-amount>
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#xformed-data"/>
                <p:output name="data" id="converted"/>
            </p:processor>
            <p:processor name="oxf:http-serializer">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <!-- NOTE: XML converter specifies content-type -->
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#converted"/>
            </p:processor>
        </p:when>
        <!-- Non XML documents -->
        <p:when test="/document[@xsi:type]">
            <p:processor name="oxf:http-serializer">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <!-- NOTE: use content-type specified on root element -->
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#xformed-data"/>
            </p:processor>
        </p:when>
        <!-- No particular document format detected. Output plain XML. -->
        <p:otherwise>
            <!-- Convert and serialize to XML -->
            <p:processor name="oxf:xml-converter">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                        <indent>false</indent>
                        <indent-amount>0</indent-amount>
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#xformed-data"/>
                <p:output name="data" id="converted"/>
            </p:processor>
            <p:processor name="oxf:http-serializer">
                <p:input name="config">
                    <config>
                        <!-- NOTE: XML converter specifies application/xml content-type -->
                    </config>
                </p:input>
                <p:input name="data" href="#converted"/>
            </p:processor>
        </p:otherwise>
    </p:choose>

</p:config>
```

Comment: Details about how to reproduce this please.

Comment: i had add in the details in my post above. Thanks

Comment: Anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Sorry but there is not enough information. You only provide your `theme.xsl`. That seems to access `input:session`, but there is no such input in standard. You must have changes to `epilogue-servlet.xpl`. Also, you mention tabs but there are no tabs I can see.

Comment: the tab coding is inside the theme.xsl. and i had added in the epilogue-servlet.xpl into my post above.

Comment: i will provide more information if need.